# bootstrap date-picker with multiple dates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I wan't a date picker in which I can change years when clicking on year and Months when clicking on Month of date picker, also I want to select multiple dates the thing is I used both selectMultiple:true and multiDate:true but it's not working and I want to modify the UI(design) of date picker but I am really stuck... I also want help with what bootstrap and jquery links should I use for this..

Answer (score 0):

If you're limited to Bootstrap only, you could do something like this:

```
[codepen]https://codepen.io/ranjith555/pen/OyKjjm
```

If you're open to using other libraries, you can try:

https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#selecting-multiple-dates